# How to add some text after end editing UITextfield in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to add some strings after end editing in `UITextField`.

Example :

> textfield 1 : user input 1000 . After focus to textfield2,I want to add "miles" to textfield1. => textfield1 : 1000 miles
>
> And if user focus to textfield1 again, it shows only 1000 for user edit, do not have "miles".

I tried but it not work

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([textfield1 isFirstResponder] && (textfield1 != touch.view))
    {
        textfield1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"miles"];
    }
    
    if ([textfield2 isFirstResponder] && (textfield2 != touch.view))
    {
        ....
    }     
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [UITextFieltDelegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this,

```
- (void)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text=@"";
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textfield1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles",textField.text];
}
```

here `textFieldDidEndEditing` is textField's delegate method. you need to set `textfield1.delegate=self`.
hope this code will help you.

Comment: @ Krishna: this can be solved by clearing textField in textFieldShouldBeginEditing method.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the delegate methods of UITextField to do this

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

and

```
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag==10) // textfield 1
    {
        if(![ _txt1.text rangeOfString:@"miles"].location!= NSNotFound)
        {
            _txt1.text = [_txt1.text stringByAppendingString:@"miles"];
        }
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 20) // textfield 2
    {
        if([ _txt1.text rangeOfString:@"miles"].location!= NSNotFound)
        {
            _txt1.text = [_txtUser1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"miles" withString:@""];
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:- Set tag to your textfields as 10 & 20.
`_txt1` is your textfield1 (`UITextfield`)

Answer (score 1):

Make `text` global variable of `NSString` and then

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
       if(text.length>0)
       {   
          self.textField.text =text;
       }
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        text =self.txtField.text;
        self.txtField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles", text];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the delagate of your textfield, like below

```
@interface YourController : UIViewController <UITextFeildDelegate>
```

and then use the following methods to check

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 if(textField....) //condition to check textfeild is
  {
   //do your stuff

  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

set tag for textField1 like this

```
  self.textField1.tag = 100;
```

on viewDidLoad to your textField outlet, then

```
  -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
         if (textField.tag == 100)
         {
              self.txtUserId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles", self.txtUserId.text];
         }
   }
```

since this is a delegate method it will fire for each textField end edit event that is why you have to check with tag number. and dont forget to set the delegate

```
   @interface YourController : UIViewController <UITextFeildDelegate>
```